# How to display array of images within Zend?

Tags: php, ajax, image, zend-framework

I have an array of images as strings pulled from the DB, I am pulling these into the browser by means of an ajax call. I've got the controller action setup and am able to view the image arrays with associated data, but when I attempt to render the images by iterating over the array and preceding each string with a header, only the first image display. I am assuming this is because either the browser is unable to determine the length of each image string, or Zend is sending the headers first and then the image data, I am uncertain. I have tried multiple methods of encapsulation, output buffering, etc. with 0 success.

We are attempting to avoid keeping these images on disk, otherwise I'd simply be storing the path and id and reflecting this in the view helper. Is there an obvious approach here that I'm missing? Or possibly a feature of Zend I'm unaware of to facilitate what I'm trying to do?

UPDATE: I added the solution I ended up with below.

Comment: But but but... the images in the db are on the disk you are not saving space no?

Comment: The problem here being that the images are already in the DB, and this is a session based interaction where the user would be able to access these resources only while they were logged in. Writing/deleting/rewriting and or trying to track when a client/browser had loaded/reloaded/refreshed the resource was looking to be far too messy to track. I'm appending the solution I ended up going with to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a rather simple solution; creating two actions within the same controller. The first constructed the markup for the images, iterating over an array created from the model function that pulled all the images for a particular client/event, this would produce:

```
<img src="/controller/action/imgKey/12345/" />
```

The second action would accept the resource request from the image, get the imgKey by _request->getParam(); and then serve the header and string for each image. This allowed me to utilize the user authentication and session schemes already in use. Maybe this approach will be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return more images via one `HTTP` request.

In your setup I can imagine following solutions:

- return data of more images as custom structure - e.g. `json` object, `XML` document... and place them in the correct `HTML` elements using `JavaScript`,
- put the images inline in the `HTML` during generation of the `HTML` page

There can be other solutions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your **.phtml

```
<?php foreach($this->images as $image) :?>
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base46_encode($image['code']) ;?>/>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

or data:image/png or data:image/gif

Comment: I had considered this approach, though I've used it in the past and run into the problem where IE has a 32k limit on data:uri, and breaking up images into sections would become too difficult to maintain.